# How to avoid overwriting a SQL UPDATE statement when looping through list in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, python-2.7

I would like to iterate through my 2D list in python and make the elements similar. I want to update my database (mySQL) with IDs of index 0 to be like index 1.

```
list_one = [ [1,3], [2,5], [3,1], [4,5], [5,2] ]


loop 1: UPDATE 1 with 3 
>> list_one[0] == 3
loop 2: UPDATE 2 with 5
>> list_one[1] == 5
loop 3: UPDATE 3 with 1
>> list_one[2] == 1

## if you look closely, the first loop will be re-updated by the third loop because list_one[0] is currently == 3.
## So loop 1 will also output as 1 along with loop 3. list_one[0] is overwritten.
>> list_one[0] == 1
```

How can I avoid this from happening? Is there a query in mySQL I can write to update everything at once? If there is, I don't know how many arrays I will have. I am using python, django and mysql. Please help, thank you!

---

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, I would like to clean the input data first, we can remove the list element which will be re-updated,for your case is `[3,1]` and `[5,2]`, after that the cleaned input will be `[[1, 3], [2, 5], [4, 5]]`, with this input, the overwrite will not happen for same IDs:

```
list_one = [ [1,3], [2,5], [3,1], [4,5], [5,2] ]
list_two = []
for i in list_one:
    if i[0] not in [el[1] for el in list_two]:
        list_two.append(i)
print(list_two) #here list_two will be [[1, 3], [2, 5], [4, 5]]
```

`list_two` will be `[[1, 3], [2, 5], [4, 5]]`, then do your update.

Comment: Ahh so separate them into two list? I also realize that if I start my update from the element that has the lowest index[1], It will prevent from overwriting anything. Let try your idea. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just tried it and both lists returns the same element in the same order.

Comment: @Marvin, are you sure you are using the correct code above? `list_one` is `[ [1,3], [2,5], [3,1], [4,5], [5,2] ]`, and after apply the code, `list_two` will be `[[1, 3], [2, 5], [4, 5]]`.